# Should I use ObjectID or uid(implemented by myself) to identify user?

Tags: mongodb, user-identification, database

I am new to `mongodb` and database.
Implement a function to make `uid` and use the local `ObjectId`.
Which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should leave ObjectID generation to the clients/drivers. This makes sure that generated IDs are unique among many things, such as time, server and process. Using the standard ObjectID also means that methods implemented by drivers (such as getTimestamp()) work.

However, if you are thinking of using your *own* type of ID for the _id field (ie, not the standard ObjectID type), then that makes a viable choice. For example, if you want to store information about a twitter user, then using the user's twitter ID as _id value makes perfect sense. Personally, I try to rely on the ObjectID type as little as I have to, as often collections will have a field in each document already that uniquely identifies each document.

Comment: Suppose i use _id(my own type) and i use that to be user indentifier. which is better,  use a auto-incrementing `number` or the user's log id(unique, string).

Comment: Don't use a auto-increment number on the client side as this won't work if you have more than one thread at the same time without some expensive locking.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on three things:

- Its source
- Where and how are you using the user ID?
- Personal opinion.

My personal opinion is that the object ID is good enough, however, getting back to the first and second point.

If this ID comes or is to be used in another database like an SQL database you might find using an incrementing ID a good idea, but SQL and other techs do fully support the object ID in the hexadecimal form.

If this ID is something that can be used much like an account number (think of your account number for car insurance when you phone them up) you might find an object ID too difficult for your users to remember/recounter as such a more human friendly ID might be more applicable here.

So it really depends on how this ID is being used.

Comment: Suppose i use _id(my own type) and i use that to be user indentifier. which is better, use a auto-incrementing `number` or the user's log id(unique, string).

Comment: @uoryon As I said it all depends on the scenario really but if the stuff I said above does not matter then object id easily