# Use Number or ObjectId when storing a reference to another document using Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

As an example, say we have two Mongoose defined schemas, one for the *users* collection and one for the *posts* collection.

Each *post* document will need to store the associated `userId` (one *user* can have many *posts*.)

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
        name: String
    });

var PostSchema = new Schema({
        userId: Number,
        title: String
    });
```

I'll be inserting the `userId` manually into the instance of a *post* document via `userDoc._id` and am trying to figure out what the data type should be for the `PostSchema.userId`.

Would it be `Number` or `Schema.Types.ObjectId`?

Comment: It can be whatever you want it to be. In this case if you want it to refer  `userId` in the `PostSchema` to the `UserSchema` **without** altering the `_id` property in the `UserSchema` then it would be `ObjectId` in order to match the type, which is the "default". Note though that such a definition whilst valid may not be what you want for "easy" resolution, and you would be resolving manually. See [Populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) in the mongoose documentaion.

Comment: @neil-lunn In that case I would use `ObjectId` or `Schema.Types.ObjectId`? The latter I presume?

Answer (score 1):

I would make it an `ObjectId` and reference it to a `User` model. This would make it easier to [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) the user if need be later on.

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    title: String
});
```

Comment: Yes, I encountered the `ref` option within an [example given in the Mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) and is part of the reason for my confusion. Using the first example on that page, the `_creator` field was defined as a `Number` yet it stores an ObjectId from the `person` schema, which really threw me - I thought it should be defined as per your definition using `Schema.Types.ObjectId` rather than `Number`.

Comment: Someone has written an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18210134/1022914) regarding the example. This is also a good read of whether you should use [ObjectId or something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426490/should-i-use-objectid-or-uidimplemented-by-myself-to-identify-user). Unless you have a reason to use something else, just use ObjectId.

Comment: In case the reference is self than do i need to add Same Schema name as a value of ref property?